# Error "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: simctl for class: groovy.lang.Binding" observed while executing from Jenkins piepline

Tags: python, mobile-automation, ios, jenkins-pipeline, mac

Team,
I am facing below error while executing Jenkins pipeline :

> **groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: simctl for class: groovy.lang.Binding**

I have checked and confirmed,

- The cmd I am trying to run using shell is working as expected when tried manually running in terminal
- The groovy script is correct and with expected syntax + valid methods

Let me know if anyone has fix this earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution :

- Actually **variable which doesn't belongs to groovy** was the culprit.
  Example `"$(variable)"`
- **Solution 1 :** Apply "{" instead of "(" in groovy script. Example `"${varible}"`

  OR
- **Solution 2 :** Add "" as prefix to the variable Example `"\$(variable)"`
- **Recommended**. Solution 2 works for me in all the other flows.